# How do fread and fwrite distinguish between different data (types) in C?

Tags: c, struct

I am working with a program and C (with Ubuntu and its bash) and using it to manipulate binary data files. First of all, when I use `fopen(filename, 'w')` it creates a file but without any extension. However, when I use `vim filename` it opens it up in some binary form.

For this question, when I use `fwrite(array, sizeof(some struct), # of structs, filePointer)` it writes (which I am not sure how in binary) into the file. When I use `fread(anotherArray, sizeof(same struct), same # of structs, anotherFilePointer)` it somehow magically knows how to read each struct in binary form and puts it into the array just by knowing its size and how much to read. What happens if I put a decimal value less than the number of structs there are in the `# of structs` parameter? How would `fread` know what to read correctly? How does it work in reading data just by looking at the sizes and not knowing what type of data it is?

Comment: Well, `fread/fwrite` read and write bytes (binary data - if you write out then read in the same number of bytes -- you get the same thing back). If you want to read and write text where you need to worry about line-breaks, etc.., `fgets/fputs`. or `fprintf`

Comment: Okay, so what happens if I don't put in the correct exact amount of bytes to read? Would an error come? How would it know what to store in the array?

Comment: Then the buffer you fill with `fread` won't be interpreted as a valid *whatever it is* you are trying to read. It will be FUBAR. Think about it. In your question above, you write a `some struct` out. What will it be if you read only 2/3 of `some struct` back in?

Comment: What is FUBAR ?

Comment: [FUBAR](https://acronymfinder.com/FUBAR.html).

Comment: *Fouled Up Beyond All Recognition* (choose your own F'word to suit your taste `:)`

Comment: Ha, okay thanks. So, anyone wants to give an answer I can accept?

Comment: It's probably a question you may want to delete -- you really answer it yourself. Just change `How does it work` in your last sentence to `It works` and you have it. (replace `'?'` with `'.'`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Haha, guess I didn't realize it. So I guess I can never know what I read in with `fread` unless I know what I wrote to it in with `fwriite`? Also, I guess I'll leave my question since maybe another person might find it helpful.

Comment: Right, look at the type for your buffer in [fwrite(3) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite) it is type `void *`. It's just a starting address for `fwrite` to use in writing however many bytes you told it to write. (obviously you know what it is writing) The same for `fread` -- it just reads `bytes` -- you have to know what you are reading (or at least the format of it). That's what binary I/O is about, it's all just bytes -- it's up to you, the Programmer, to know what you are writing and reading and how to unpack it. Otherwise, use formatted-I/O and lines, words, etc..

Comment: Okay, thanks. But just to be sure, you technically can still `fwrite` text and `fread` them to human-readable text format?

Comment: It's like "puzzle pieces on a ribbon" you pull out of a box. Only if you pull them over their original frame, they will "snap in".

Comment: @Holger Not really sure what "puzzles pieces on a ribbon" are. Also, can you answer my last comment on `fread` and `fwrite` on text?

Comment: `fread` and `fwrite` only read and write bytes. If these bytes contain human-readable text or the bit pattern of a 32-bit integer value doesn't matter. You only have to read each byte in the same way you wrote it. If you wrote 10 bytes of text and an integer value (32 bit/4 bytes), you have to read exactly 10 bytes and an integer. You can't read only 7 bytes and then the integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fwrite` writes the bytes of the memory where the object is stored to the output stream and `fread` reads bytes from the input stream into the memory whose address it gets as an argument. No assumption is made regarding the types and representations of the C objects stored in this memory.

Hence a number of problems can occur:

- the representation of basic types can differ from one compiler to another, one machine to another, one OS to another, possibly even depending on compiler switches. Writing the bytes of the memory representation of basic types makes sense only if you know you will be reading the file back into byte-compatible structures.
- the mode for accessing the input and output files matters: as you mention, files must be open in binary mode to avoid any translation between memory representation and file contents such as what happens for text files on legacy systems. For example text mode on MS-Windows causes `0A` bytes to convert to `0D` `0A` sequences on output and `0D` bytes to be stripped on input, resulting in different contents for isolated `0D` bytes in the initial content.
- if the C structure contains pointers, the bytes written to the output represent the **value** of these pointers, not what they point to. Reading these values back into memory is highly likely to create invalid pointers and very unlikely to make any sense.
- if the C structure has a flexible array at the end, its contents is not included in the `sizeof(T)` bytes written by `fwrite` or read by `fread`.
- the C structure may contain padding between members, causing the output file to contain non  deterministic bytes, which might be a problem in some circumstances.
- if the C structure has arrays with only partial meaningful contents, such as `char` arrays containing C strings, beware that `fwrite` will write the bytes beyond the null terminator, which should not be meaningful, but might be sensitive information such as password fragments or other meaningful data. Carefully erasing such arrays may avoid this issue, but padding bytes cannot be erased reliably, so this solution is not perfect.

For all the above reasons and other ones, reading/writing binary data is to be reserved to very specific cases where the programmer knows exactly what is happening. For other purposes, saving as text files in human readable form is much preferred.

Answer (score 0):

In question comments from @David C. Rankin

"Well, fread/fwrite read and write bytes (binary data - if you write out then read in the same number of bytes -- you get the same thing back). If you want to read and write text where you need to worry about line-breaks, etc.., fgets/fputs. or fprintf"

> So I guess I can never know what I read in with fread unless I know what I wrote to it in with fwriite?

"Right, look at the type for your buffer in fwrite(3) - Linux man page it is type void *. It's just a starting address for fwrite to use in writing however many bytes you told it to write. (obviously you know what it is writing) The same for fread -- it just reads bytes -- you have to know what you are reading (or at least the format of it). That's what binary I/O is about, it's all just bytes -- it's up to you, the Programmer, to know what you are writing and reading and how to unpack it. Otherwise, use formatted-I/O and lines, words, etc.."

Comment: Please, please, don't use Stackoverflow as a forum! This is in the _answers_ section, but isn't an _answer_. Read [ask]!

Comment: @dandan78 Well it answers my question so therefore is an answer?

Comment: Sorry, it looked like you were responding to a comment in your answer.

Comment: @dandan78 No problem